# Is 'ar-extensions' ruby gem work on PostgreSql-8.4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, postgresql-8.4

I want information about the ar-extensions gem work on postgresql-8.4.If it works means please give some related information

Answer (score 0):

It should work (as in the API should be fine), but it doesn't provide any performance boosts as I did not regularly or actively use postgresql back then and still haven't built postgresql optimized functionality. I am waiting for a postgresql user to submit a patch or at least show me what the "postgresql" efficient way would be, but to this day I have yet to see either from the postgresql crowd.

Please note that ar-extensions should only be used for Rails 2.x and activerecord-import should be used for Rails 3.x. Also, the finder extensions available in ar-extensions are no longer supported in activerecord-import so those definitely won't work.